# wcf restful web service with post method

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I'm developing on asp.net using vs2017; I'm working on a web service now. 
I have a problem with wcf rest web service ,
I used below code for connecting to web service with GET method.

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "json/{id}")]
    string JSONData(string id);
```

and now I want to change method to "POST" . How can I send parameters with this method?

in client side

```
<form id="form1" action="RestServiceWareHouse.svc/jsonUserLogin"  method="post">
    <div>
        <input id="id" name="id" type="text" />
        <input id="pass" name="pass" type="text" />
        <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

But I can't send parameters.

in server side my function for auth users

```
  public string JSONDataLogin(string username,string password)
    {
        DataBaseConnectionClass GetUserList = new DataBaseConnectionClass();
        response = GetUserList.select("my select query are here");



        if (response.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            return js.Serialize("true");
        }
        return js.Serialize("no found");
    }
```

my code in GET method looks good, but in POST method I can't get parameters.

Comment: What type data you want to send in POST?

Comment: Object or list or single String

Comment: the post will look like this 
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "methodName",ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

Comment: thanks guys, I recently changed method to POST but not work
and my Parameters is string for login and for others is json data . my input : string and json------- output:json

Comment: Put your asp.net source code also!

Comment: replace this line `string username,string password` with a class having these as the properties

Comment: i changed but my problem not solved

Comment: my edited code is  string JSONDataLogin(RequestData rData);
 public class RequestData
    {
       
            [DataMember]
            public string id { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string pass { get; set; }
        
    }

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a Restful post action using WCF then try adding below attribute to your action

```
   [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "getdata",ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
   [OperationContract(Name = "PostData"), FaultContract(typeof(CustomFault))]
   ResponseModel PostData(InputModel requestData);
```

From the client post data using `Post` as the action and in the body pass parameters as

```
{
  "Key": "Value"
}
```

If your `InputModel` contains following properties

```
public class InputModel
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: my response is json format. how to can i handle it. thanks

Comment: in the method just return ResponseModel which will be sent as json to the clinet

Comment: i can call another function without parameters, but i can't call this function with parameters

Comment: Can't understand your problem. Please post some more code and use case

Comment: Not here edit your question and add with proper format

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
     [OperationContract]
     [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
     BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
     ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/json")]
     void PostData(string id);
```

Comment: I used but response isn't true. say "Method not allowed"

Comment: please share the body data  and UriTemplate with me

Comment: Hence I can try in my local machine

Comment: How do you issue a request to check? Using PostMan or Fiddler?

Comment: i have 2 function (first without parameters and second with parameters). first is ok in postman. but i want send 2 parameters to second function , not work, and say parameters is null

Comment: thanks guys. my problem solved. i change some code then problem solved. i used parameters as string and send parameters as json format

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace RestService
{        
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface RestServiceWareHouse
    {

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "/jsonUserList")]
        string JSONData();
    }
}
```

my function in .svc file

```
public string JSONData()
{return "json format data";}
```